# OSX, what are these invisible directories with random strings for names?

Tags: macos

On my desktop, there is a directory called .CjlqgySsIMk=, and inside it there are two files:

XJ5LTgVvrEk=
and
110E80392142D917

Any idea of what these could be, or how I could figure out their creators?

**edit:**

Here's some info from similar files in my Documents folder (I deleted the .CjlqgySsIMk one)

`drwxrwxrwx@    3 rob  rob     102 Jun 18  2008 .L0RBH0FUANLIHJ4KSMOF3AHG`

and inside that directory:
`-rw-rw-rw-@  1 rob  rob   242 Aug 11  2008 42CDCED929495D41`

and

`$ file 42CDCED929495D41

42CDCED929495D41: data`

Comment: How old are they? I suspect remnants of a software installer or otherwise temporary files you could just delete.

Comment: They are _very_ old. 2006.

Comment: If you could open up a terminal and run `ls -al` inside the folder, that will give us some more information.

Comment: Also if you could run "file <filename>" for those files to determine filetypes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes hidden files like these (named with a seemingly random set of numbers and letters) are key files used by a third party application to facilitate a copy protection mechanism. They can crop up in a variety unexpected places in an attempt at security through obscurity.

This behaviour goes against the Apple's suggested practise for where an applications support files should be placed.

One downside is that these files may persist long after you have deleted the original application. A possible side affect of removing them is that the associated application may react as though you are attempting to break its copy protection.

Tracking down the related application can be troublesome. The related application may not access the file every time it is used or the related application may no longer exist.

You could try the following:

- Open the Terminal and enter:
  `sudo opensnoop -v -f filepath`
- Type your password when requested
- run various programs to see if they access the file

You may eventually see some output. This will contain the command name for the process that accessed the file.

- Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to stop opensnoop running in the terminal